# Firefox columns not rendering right

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, tumblr

I'm creating my own Tumblr theme. All the post I created on Tumblr will show inside a div that has a:

```
-moz-column-count: 3;
-moz-column-gap: 0px;
```

And ofc the versions for other browsers like -webkit-

For some reasen when I load the webpage on Firefox. The columns will not appear next to each other, but you see them under each other. But Firefox sees that it has to be 3 columns. There is plenty enough space next to the first column post.

**Example chrome:**
[image]

**Example in FireFox**
[image]

When I open the element inspect from Firefox. The columns posts will be showed next to each other like Chrome version. When I remove the element inspect, it's back to what you see on the image.